# How does the Bayesian Information Criterion work for model selection?

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, model, bic, differences

I am aware that we can use the BIC values from different models in order to determine which model predicts the data best. However, I'm a little confused about the criteria used to determine which model is better over another model.

For the BIC, a difference of 2 is considered as positive evidence for one model over the other and a difference greater than 10 suggests very strong evidence in favor of one model over the other.

Let's assume one model has a BIC of 7461 and another has a BIC of 7508. The two models differ by 47. Therefore, we would conclude that the model with BIC 7461 explains the data the best. Below are my questions about this conclusion/interpretation:

1. What are the units of the BIC numbers?
2. Do we have to consider the proportion of difference between the two models in our interpretation?
3. Does a difference of 2 always indicate positive evidence for one model over the other regardless of the BIC values? For example, a BIC(1) = 10 vs BIC(2) = 12 has a difference of 2 and proportionally BIC(2) is 1.2 (12/10) times greater where as BIC(1) = 7461 and BIC(2) = 7508 differ by 47 but proportionally BIC(2) is 1.006 (7508/7461) times greater.
4. Do the units matter with BIC? Or, is it always the case that a difference of 2 means positive evidence regardless of how large or small the BIC values are?

Comment: 2 or 10 for evidence or strong evidence sounds more like it came from Bayes Factors.

Comment: @fm361 This cross validated question also interprets the BIC differences based on certain values. Does this seem correct? Here is that question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111766/how-to-correctly-choose-model-based-on-bic

Comment: Intuitively, no.

Answer (score 0):

> For the BIC, a difference of 2 is considered as positive evidence for one model over the other and a difference greater than 10 suggests very strong evidence in favour of one model over the other.

Where did you get this from? I don't think it makes any sense.

---

Re: your other questions:

> What are the units of the BIC numbers?

Formally, BIC is defined as follows:
$$
\operatorname{BIC}=-2\ln\hat{L}+p\ln(n)
$$
where $\ln\hat{L}$ is the maximised value of the log-likelihood; $n$ is the number of observations; and $p$ is the number of parameters in the model.

The smaller the BIC, the better. This is because a higher maximised log-likelihood will lead to a smaller BIC. Note that BIC is penalised by the number of parameters that need to be estimated. As such, BIC tends to favour simple (more parsimonious) models.

> Do we have to consider the proportion of difference between the two models in our interpretation?

Not really. It sounds like you are worried about whether the difference between two models' BICs is statistically significant or not. In my experience, bootstrapping is the best way to do this.

> Does a difference of 2 always indicate positive evidence for one model over the other regardless of the BIC values?

No.

> Do the units matter with BIC? Or, is it always the case that a difference of 2 means positive evidence regardless of how large or small the BIC values are?

No; and definitely not.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information. It seems like you cannot say anything about the magnitude of the difference between BICs.  Is that correct @AdriaLuz @Adria? For example, if the BIC of one is 12 and the other is 13 then we say that the model with BIC 12 better explains the data. Further, if they differed by more than 1, such as 100, we would conclude the same thing and would not indicate anything about the strength of the evidence for one model over the other?

Comment: I found this response to another BIC question on cross validated. Does this seem correct when to talking about the magnitude of the difference between the BICs or is this another incorrect speculation like I found when I searched BIC information?  (1) If the absolute difference δ is greater 10, the smaller BIC value is considerably better: ∣BIC1−BIC2∣>10

(2) If the absolute difference δ is greater 5, the smaller BIC value is likely to be better.
∣BIC1−BIC2∣>5

(3) If the absolute difference δ is smaller 2, the smaller BIC does not indicate to be better than the other.
∣BIC1−BIC2∣<2

Comment: Last comment: I found the citation for the rules of thumb interpretation. Raftery, A. E. (1995). Bayesian model selection in social research. Sociological methodology, 111-163.